# Android Studio: Include library test classes in app test

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

The (relevant) part of my project's folder structure is as follows

```
├───lib
│   └───src
│       ├───androidTest
│       │   └───com.example.lib
│       │       └───utils
│       │       └───...
│       └───main
│           └───com.example.lib
│               └───...
└───mobile
    └───src
        ├───androidTest
        │   └───com.example.app
        │       └───...
        └───main
            └───com.example.app
                └───...
```

So I have the module "lib", providing reusable functionalities and the module "mobile", containing the actual app. Both modules have their own `androidTest`(Instrumentation test) where activities are tested. The lib test code also contains utility classes, e.g. `lib/src/androidTest/com.example.app/utils/TestUtils.java`:

```
package com.example.lib;

/**
 * Utility functions for tests
 */
public class TestUtils {

    public static Matcher<View> nthChildOf(final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int childPosition) {
        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("with " + childPosition + " child view of type parentMatcher");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
                if (!(view.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup)) {
                    return parentMatcher.matches(view.getParent());
                }

                ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                View child = group.getChildAt(childPosition);
                return parentMatcher.matches(view.getParent()) && child != null && child.equals(view);
            }
        };
    }
    ...
```

Using this `TestUtils` class from the lib test module works but when I call them from the mobile test module, the compiler complains:

> Error:(28, 19) error: cannot find symbol class TestUtils

e.g. in the file `mobile/src/androidTest/com.example.app/SettingActivityTest.java`:

```
package com.example.app;
import de.ioxp.lib.TestUtils; // This line results in the error, but IntelliJ opens the correct file when clicking on it.

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class SettingActivityTest {
    ...
```

So my question is: **How can I use classes from my library's test suite in my main app's test suite?**

I already added an explicit `androidTestCompile` for the library to my mobile/build.gradle , but this did not have any result:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':lib')
    androidTestCompile project(':lib') // this line makes no difference, maybe I have to address the lib's testing directly. But how?

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2';
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
}
```

Comment: @PhiLab, Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

That's because androidTest part of your library in not compile into mobile target. There's two ways to resolve this issue.

You can move test util class to your library sources(main), or you can move test util to external lib and add it through testAndroidCompile in your library and mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but I ran into the following problem: the test utility classes need classes from the lib module. So I get a circular dependency ``lib <-> testLib`` which is not possible. Example: I have a special IdlingResource for a custom View class. Both are needed in the library tests and the actual app's test

Comment: This is why you should make test lib which will be added by androidTest Compile in both projects. By the way - good to know that there're some developers who are writing tests ;)

Comment: My testlib has a ``MyViewIdlingResource`` which tests ``MyView`` from the library project. So the test lib adds the library in thegradle file: ``compile project(':lib')``. Now, I can't write in my library gradle file ``androidTestCompile project(':testLib')`` because this would induce a circular dependency. And I use the ``MyViewIdlingResource`` in the main project's tests as well, so I can't move it to the lib's testing file.